# awk and echo commands in python

Tags: python, awk

I need to use `echo` and `awk` commands in python script. Can you help me?

I have a bash script, there is an example:

```
while read LINE
    do
        BOM1=`echo "$LINE" | awk -F $'\t' '{print $1}'`
        BOM2=`echo "$LINE" | awk -F $'\t' '{print $2}'`
done < file.txt
```

I try to rewrite the same in python script:

```
import subprocess

with open(PT_tmp_bom_list,"r+") as Tmp_list_file:
    for line in Tmp_list_file:
        cmd="echo {} | awk -F '\t' '{print $1}'".format(line)
        subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

I have a several questions:

1. If line is a string. I cannot output it, tried:
   `cmd="echo {} ".format(line)`

   it says that: `The system cannot find the file specified.` It means, I can't get a line for `awk`.

   The line should look like:

   `<deliverydir>/bom/bom_list.txt**TAB**<bom_list_dir>/bom_list.txt**TAB**Internal   User`

The second question, if i get a line from `echo`, how should I use awk command for this line?

Comment: `python` itself has different modules for text processing and why would you want to use `awk` for it

Comment: @Inian  Because want to be close to current results from bash script, that's why tried to use methods which are used there.

Comment: instead of the `cmd=` part just do `tmp=line.split()` and you'll have everything in a nice array, no need for subprocess or echo or awk...

Comment: The error message is probably because the shell interprets `<` and `>` as redirection operators. You can fix that by quoting the `echo` argument but really, just get rid of that horrible pretzel logic.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely do not need external programs for this; Python easily subsumes the functionality of Awk and then some.

```
with open(PT_tmp_bom_list,"r+") as Tmp_list_file:
    for line in Tmp_list_file:
        bom1, bom2, _ = line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
```

Take out the `, _` if the lines have exactly two fields.